# How to plot a histogram in python from a dictionary data more than 40000?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I tried to plot a histogram by using the data from a dictionary. For example, if I have 9 data in a dictionary, I can easily plot the histogram as below:

```
myDictionary = {'you': 27, 'apple': 1, 'mango': 72, 'watermelon': 62, 'juice': 33, 'peter': 36, 'vegetable': 20, 'meat': 12, 'egg': 9}

plt.bar(myDictionary.keys(), myDictionary.values(), width=0.5, color='g')
```

However, if there is 42000 data in the dictionary, it takes too long for the plot to come out, in fact I'm not sure the plot will appear or not because I didn't wait for the histogram to come out.

Is there any solution can solve this problem? I'm not sure what other method can be use in order to get the histogram. Further, the x-axis will be very untidy as there are too many labels (42000).

Comment: You cannot possibly expect to reasonably fit 42000 'columns' in a screen of even the highest resolution.   Do you have 42000 pixels on your X axis?  I doubt it.  So, you'll have to group things into manageable chunks.

Comment: You are using the `bar` function. Why not use matplotlib's `hist` function? You've mentioned the word histogram here 4 times!

Comment: Not to mention that a histogram with 40k bars is unintelligible. I think you probably want to look into "binning" because you just have raw data at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you'd extract the values from your dictionary to a `pandas` series to speed up indexing. You can then plot this series directly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

myDictionary = {'you': 27, 'apple': 1, 'mango': 72, 'watermelon': 62, 'juice': 33, 'peter': 36, 'vegetable': 20, 'meat': 12, 'egg': 9}

# First, convert to a series
s = pd.Series(x for x in myDictionary.values())
# Plot your series directly
s.hist()
plt.show()
```